# Backend for NativeScript providing code for Web, iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, angular, firebase, nativescript

I'm a front-end developer and I am going to write an application in NativeScript because I can use Angular. Besides, I can can save time and create a website and applications for iOS and Android.

I'm considering several possibilities:

- Using Firebase, but I do not know if it is possible to share one
  resource (database etc) between 3 solutions (web / ios / android) at
  the same time.
- I know a bit PHP and I was thinking about some micro framework with
  OAuth 2.0 integration

What are your experiences? The application will contain a large database of products, photos, ratings, comments and a small community.

Comment: I think Firebase would be cool. I know right now my app is using AWS which handles everything web/ios/android. Although, it's a bit pricier. I think Nativescript's firebase plugin should handle the iOS and Android, and then configure your website to just connect to same Firebase database. It should be doable and fast to set up!